# Problem installing default-jdk/jre

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, java, dependencies

I'm trying to install default-jre-headless and default-jdk but everytime I do that I get:

```
[sudo] password for reizu: 
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Get:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease [7,343 B]      
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.4 kB]
Get:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [3,316 B]                 
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,084 B]
Get:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable/main amd64 Packages [3,790 B]
Get:7 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages [1,171 B]    
Get:8 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages [1,650 B]   
Fetched 35.6 kB in 8s (4,502 B/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
(xenial)reizu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package default-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'default-jre' has no installation candidate
(xenial)reizu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package default-jre-headless
(xenial)reizu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package default-jdk
```

When i do sudo apt-get upgrade

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 minecraft-launcher : Depends: default-jre but it is not installable
 multimc : Depends: qt5-default but it is not installable
           Recommends: openjdk-8-jre but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When i do sudo apt --fix-broken install i get

```
(xenial)reizu@localhost:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  minecraft-launcher multimc
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 76.8 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 107750 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing minecraft-launcher (2.2.1441) ...
Removing multimc (1.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
(xenial)reizu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I installed minecraft by doing `sudo dpkg --install --force-depends Minecraft.deb`
Because i couldn't install default-jdk, can someone help me install it. I have searched everywhere, I went to the Ubuntu website and everything.

Changes, i did everything my replies said and now when i do sudo apt-get update i get this, am i good now to download jdk? also can yall tell me how to do it safely? Thanks!

````
(xenial)reizu@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done ```
````

Comment: You cannot find them because you have no Ubuntu repositories listed in your sources. Just PPAs and third parties. See [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Gentle reminder: Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) reaches the end of Community Support in April 2021. After that, we won't answer questions about it anymore.

Comment: You have added the webupd8team ppa for java. It is *empty*. There are zero java packages in it. You should remove it. This has been the case for nearly two years. https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Comment: Thank You for the suggestions, lemme do everything yall have suggested. Also, im using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Xenial

Comment: I have editted my response ^ am i good now? and how do i install default JDK safely.